# AssertionError: Template was not a template used to render the response

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm encountering an issue with my TestCase where it's asserting that the actual template used to render a response doesn't match the template I'm expecting. The error being raised is:

- `AssertionError: False is not true : Template 'posts/question.html' was not a template used to render the response. Actual template(s) used: posts/ask.html, ..., ...`

Everything after `posts/ask.html` refers to built-in templates.

Sequence of events involved:

- Click "Ask Question" -> post QuestionForm -> redirect to question page -> click edit -> post question edits -> redirect to question page

I cannot pinpoint where or why Django is saying that `posts/ask.html` is being rendered. As far as I can tell I'm redirecting to the right URL where it's suppose to render `posts/question.html`.

```
class TestPostEditQuestionPage(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a message is displayed to the user in the event
    that some aspect of the previous posted question was edited.'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username="OneAndOnly",
            password="passcoderule"
        )
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=cls.user)
        tag = Tag.objects.create(name="TagZ")
        question = Question.objects.create(
            title="This is Question Infinity",
            body="The is the content body for This is Question Infinity",
            profile=profile
        )
        question.tags.add(tag)

        cls.data = {
            "title": "This is Question Zero",
            "body": "The is the content body for This is Question Infinity",
            "tags": ["TagZ", "TagA"]
        }

    def test_posted_question_content_changed(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("posts:edit", kwargs={"id": 1}),
            data=self.data, follow=True
        )
        print([template.name for template in response.templates])
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "posts/question.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "Question updated!")
```

```
class AskQuestionPage(Page):

    template_name = "posts/ask.html"
    extra_context = {
        'title': "Ask a public question"
    }

    def attach_question_tags(self, tags):
        question_tags = []
        for name in tags:
            try:
                tag = Tag.objects.get(name=name)
            except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                tag = Tag.objects.create(name=name)
            finally:
                question_tags.append(tag)
        return question_tags

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = QuestionForm
        return context


    def post(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form'](request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tags = self.attach_question_tags(form.cleaned_data.pop("tags"))
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.profile = request.user.profile
            question.save()
            question.tags.add(*tags)
            form.save_m2m()
            return SeeOtherHTTPRedirect(
                reverse("posts:question", kwargs={"id": question.id})
            )
        return self.render_to_response(context)


class EditQuestionPage(AskQuestionPage):

    extra_context = {
        'title': "Edit your question"
    }

    def get(self, request, id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['form'] = context['form'](instance=question)
        return self.render_to_response(
            context, headers={
                'Content-Type': "text/html"
            }
        )

    def post(self, request, id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form'](request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.has_changed():
                messages.success(request, "Question updated!")
            x = form.cleaned_data.pop("tags")
            tags = self.attach_question_tags(x)
            question = form.save()
            question.tags.set(tags)
            return SeeOtherHTTPRedirect(reverse(
                "posts:question", kwargs={"id": id}
            ))
        return self.render_to_response(context)


class PostedQuestionPage(Page):

    template_name = "posts/question.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['answer_form'] = AnswerForm
        return context

    def get(self, request, id):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        context['question'] = question
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

```
posts_patterns = ([
    path("", pv.QuestionListingPage.as_view(), name="main"),
    path("questions/ask/", pv.AskQuestionPage.as_view(), name="ask"),
    path("questions/edit/<id>/", pv.EditQuestionPage.as_view(), name="edit"),
    path("questions/<id>/", pv.PostedQuestionPage.as_view(), name="question")
], "posts")
```